# Is there no way for Csharp to write a truly static λ expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

Language     : C#
.Net Version : 8.0
IDE          : VS2020 / VSCode
OS           : Windows11

#### Is there no way for Csharp to write a truly static λ expression?

I studied currying today and wrote a function :

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Curryfy;

object Apply(Delegate _operator, object? arg1)
{
    Type t = _operator.GetType();
    if (!t.IsGenericType || t.GenericTypeArguments.Length < 2 || t.Name != "Func`" + t.GenericTypeArguments.Length)
        throw new Exception();

    var args = _operator.Method.GetParameters().Select(p => Expression.Variable(p.ParameterType)).ToArray();
    Expression expression = Expression.Call(_operator.Method, args);
    foreach (var arg in args.Reverse())
        expression = *Expression.Lambda(expression, arg);*
    Console.WriteLine(expression);
    return null;
}
***int sum(int a, int b) => a + b;***
System.Console.WriteLine(sum);
Apply(sum, 10);
```

It can run correctly and the results are as I expected :

```
System.Func`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32]
Param_0 => Param_1 => <<Main>$>g__sum|0_1(Param_0, Param_1)
```

This sum function doesn't even use 'static'.
But when I change this line to :

`Func<int, int, int> sum = static (int a, int b) => a + b;`

The Expression.Call(_operator.Method, args) throw a exception said :

`Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.`

**What is the essential difference between these two ways of writing?**

#### update at 14:34 1/11/2024:

Inspired by Michael Liu, I changed these implementation of sum to :

```
var a = Expression.Variable(typeof(int));
var b = Expression.Variable(typeof(int));
var aplusb = Expression.Add(a, b);
var sumExpression = Expression.Lambda(aplusb, a, b);
var sum = sumExpression.Compile();
```

Then Expression.Call(_operator.Method, args) didn't throw any exception.

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem with the automatic formatting of the last paragraph. I didn't check it.

Comment: You can click "Edit" and edit your question.

Comment: What is the reason to envelope current method by additional LambdaExpression? Just reversing parameters?

Comment: You're declaring a method on the line you've denoted as ***. There is a difference between declaring a method static or not.  To call a static method, you would need syntax like MyClass.StaticMethod( ...) not myInstance.StaticMethod(...) which you are using in the line Apply (sum, 10).

Answer (score 5):

> What is the essential difference between these two ways of writing?

It looks like this difference in behavior is the result of a *choice* made by the current implementation of the C# compiler. When you write

```
int sum(int a, int b) => a + b;
```

the compiler generates a `static` method (even though you didn't mark it `static`), which works with the `Expression.Call(MethodInfo, Expression[])` overload that you're using.

But when you write

```
Func<int, int, int> sum = static (int a, int b) => a + b;
```

the compiler actually generates an *instance* method, even though you explicitly marked it `static`! Apparently, [this is for performance reasons](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20315) (calling a `static` method via a delegate requires some extra argument shuffling compared to calling an instance method).

You can work around this behavior by updating your code to handle instance methods:

```
Expression expression = _operator.Method.IsStatic
    ? Expression.Call(_operator.Method, args)
    : Expression.Call(Expression.New(_operator.Method.DeclaringType), _operator.Method, args);
```

This will instantiate an instance of the compiler-generated class that holds the actual implementation of your `sum` method.

**Caution:** We're depending on some implementation details of the C# compiler here, which are subject to change. If you want to write code that's guaranteed to work forever, I recommend *not* passing lambda expressions to `Apply`.

Comment: Thank you for answer,I tried using the Linq.Expressions to build my function and it looks like it works like I want,will there still be the problems mentioned in Caution?Does it become a truly static lambda expression?

Comment: I struggle with this problem because I hope that the function after currying can be uncurried.

Comment: @黎民禹: Linq.Expressions is a good alternative because you're no longer depending on implementation details of the C# compiler.  The Caution no longer applies.

Answer (score 3):

> But when I change this line to : `Func<int, int, int> sum = static (int a, int b) => a + b;`

You don't need `static` here, you will have the same issue with just:

```
Func<int, int, int> sum = (int a, int b) => a + b;
```

The thing here is that you are declaring an [anonymous function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) (lamdba) which is a kind of syntactic sugar which is handled by compiler and actually is expanded into something like the following (see yourself [@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYDcBYAUNhBWAHlgBcAaAAhIpID5yBnAVzHIF5yAKE8iamY8sACUbOhHIBqQZixA==)):

```
[Serializable]
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class TheGeneratedClass
{
    public static readonly TheGeneratedClass <>9 = new TheGeneratedClass();

    public static Func<int, int, int> <>9__0_0;

    internal int TheGeneratedMethodName(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

As you can see that the generated method (`internal int TheGeneratedMethodName(int a, int b)`) is actually an instance one which requires instance, i.e. something like the following - `new TheGeneratedClass().TheGeneratedMethodName`. I.e. in the case of anonymous lambda the expression should create an instance of the holding type. For example:

```
Expression expression = Expression.Call(
    Expression.New(_operator.Method.DeclaringType), 
    _operator.Method, 
    args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Func<T in, T out>` to store the lambda expression statically. `T in` is the data type used for the input and `T out` is the data type for the output.

```
static Func<int, int> func = x => x * x;

//

//

Console.WriteLine(func.Invoke(2));
```

You can invoke the result synchrounously using the `Invoke` method and pass the input to it.

If you want to call it asynchronously, .NET Core is not supporting the `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` calls, so you will have to call the `Invoke` method in a `Task<T>` method in order to call it asynchronously.

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static Func<int, int> func = x => x * x;
        public static void Main()
        {
            AsyncTaskProcess();
        }

        public static async void AsyncTaskProcess()
        {
            int result = await FuncExe(func, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static Task<int> FuncExe(Func<int, int> func, int param){
            return Task.FromResult(func.Invoke(param));
        }
    }
}
```